# Best Panel to use to display Object data with picture and text

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay, tried multiple ways an none seem to work. Tried making a ListBox.ItemTemplate, but that doesn't work too good as I can't get the items to stack horizontally!

Basically, I have got a Collection of Object instances with data inside, such as First and Last Name. Now I want to have a List Control which will use this Collection to display the information in the following format.

100 x 100 background image, label docked to bottom of image with the name in.

Example:

[image]

The background image URL is in the Object Instance, and so is the name.

My current code, doesn't work due to only stacking vertically, at this instance I also don't need to be able to select the items as it's for display purposes only.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logged, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource Users}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel Width="100" Height="100">
                <DockPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ThumbLoc}" />
                </DockPanel.Background>
                <Label>
                    <Label.Content>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                    <Binding Path="LastName" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Label.Content>
                </Label>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

May as well give you my Object Class and the declaration of one of the instances:

```
//Logged in users class
public class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Int16 Permissions { get; set; }
    public string ThumbLoc { get; set; }
}
```

Declaration:

```
//User logged in, add data to user object
user.Email = "email@gmail.com";
user.FirstName = "John";
user.LastName = "Johnson";
user.ID = "01";
user.Permissions = 1;

//See if user has a thumbnail picture and save it's location
string thumbLoc = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
    "\\Users\\DisplayPictures\\" +
    user.FirstName + user.LastName + ".png";

if (File.Exists(@thumbLoc))
{
    user.ThumbLoc = thumbLoc;
}
else
{
    user.ThumbLoc = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Users\\DisplayPictures\\user.png";
}
```

Best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also don't need to be able to select the items as it's for display
>   purposes only.

Instead of using ListBox, ***use ItemsControl*** which doesn't support selection of objects.

> My current code, doesn't work due to only stacking vertically.

***Set ItemsPanel to WrapPanel with Orientation set to Horizontal*** to stack items horiontally.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Logged}"
              Style="{StaticResource Users}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel Margin="4,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="100">
                <DockPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ThumbLoc}" />
                </DockPanel.Background>
                <Label>
                    <Label.Content>
                        <TextBlock>
                           <TextBlock.Text>
                              <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                 <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                 <Binding Path="LastName" />
                              </MultiBinding>
                           </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Label.Content>
                </Label>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: That makes my application exception for some reason, see my updated post.

Comment: Ah, never mind. My styling was the issue, forgot to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.

I was going to sleep that's why I can't help you more. I think you can handle the rest. :)

You can use ListView Resources for DataTemplates with Bindings.

```
<ListView x:Name="lst">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:User }">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ThumbLoc}"  Width="100" Height="100" ></Image>
                    <Label Width="100" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

Create new ListViewItem to add items on that ListView.

```
ListViewItem lw = new ListViewItem();
lw.Content = YOURCLASSWILLCOMEHERE.
lst.Items.Add(lw);
```

Using ListView, makes your items selectable, clickable, doubleclickable, dragable etc...